# R processes do not stop after R is shut down

Tags: r

I am using parallel. If my code is interrupted (e.g. with a bug, or just with a shutdown of R console) before the stopCluster(cl) code runs, then the R processes keep on running! I am using a new Macbook Pro. In my activity monitor, I can see 8 R processes running, even after I have shut down the R console. The only way I can seem to stop them is to restart my computer. I can also force quit each one individually from the activity monitor. Is there any better solution?

```
cl <- makeCluster(getOption('cl.cores', detectCores()))
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))
clusterEvalQ(cl, require(zoo))
...
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: On linux when that happens I `kill pid` the rogue R instances from terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mcKill` a low level function in `parallel` package :

> sends a signal to a child process: it is equivalent to pskill in package tools.

Example:

```
p  <- mcparallel(scan(n = 1, quiet = TRUE))
parallel:::mckill(p)
[1] TRUE
parallel:::mckill(p)  ## check that the process is really killed
Error in FUN(3202L[[1L]], ...) : 'mckill' failed
```